# Can't seem to do combined query AND sort?

Tags: query, sort

Below is the code I'm using to query multi-day events. The problem I'm having is that I can either sort by the start date (evstart_date) OR I can do a combined query against start date and end date (evend_date). But I cannot do both the combined query AND sort. The code below gets the query right (continues to display multi-day events that started in the past but have not yet ended), but the sort is broken (reverts to default sort by post date).

I've tried several variations, but have been unable to find a solution.

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 hours'));
    $upcomingevents = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'events', 
        'posts_per_page' => 6,  
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query'=>array(
        'relation'=>'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'evstart_date',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'CHAR'
                ),
            array(
                'key' => 'evend_date',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'CHAR'
                )
             ),
        'meta_key' => 'evstart_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    )); 
?>
```

Comment: What do you want to sort by?

Comment: What is the format of your dates?

Comment: I want items ordered by start date. Dates are in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: Actually, above code doesn't get the query right, either, as it shows everything in events (added some events that were past and it does not exclude them). Again, if I remove the orderby code (last 3 variables) the query works (excludes appropriate items). If I query only for start date or end date, then I can sort.

Comment: type should be `date`, not `char`. otherwise, post the SQL generated by this query, perhaps you can't sort on a key used in an `OR` relation?

Comment: Tried that, and DATE works no better. CHAR works fine when not trying to both sort and do combo query.
Format generated is yyyy-mm-dd (e.g. 2012-02-05)
Just for kicks, tried AND rather than OR and got no results, so that may indicate that the query works, but that's not a lot of help, since AND is not the query needed to return proper results.
Also created a new startdate custom field (same data, but different keyname) and cannot sort on that, either, with combination query (even though that key is not used in the query).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem until I realized you don't actually have to query by the event start date, only the end date.

As long as the event's end date has not past it doesn't matter whether the start date is in the future or not. All you have to do is grab all the dates that have not ended yet then you can order them by their start date.

This should work for you:

> ```
> <?php
>     $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
>     $today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 hours'));
>     $upcomingevents = new WP_Query(array(
>         'post_type' => 'events', 
>         'posts_per_page' => 6,  
>         'paged' => $paged,
>         'meta_query'=>array(
>             array(
>                 'key' => 'evend_date',
>                 'value' => $today,
>                 'compare' => '>=',
>                 'type' => 'CHAR'
>                 )
>              ),
>         'meta_key' => 'evstart_date',
>         'orderby' => 'meta_value',
>         'order' => 'ASC'
>     )); 
> ?>
> ```

Comment: I finally came to the same conclusion, Christian; hadn't gotten round to posting it as an answer. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Great answer Christian. Welcome to the site, keep providing good answers like this; the site needs them.